How can I save Rendered display render preview image from shading viewport?
I want to save a rendered preview image with all the materials, lighting, etc. that is being continuosly rendered in the Rendered display render preview in shading viewport. Is this even possible? If I press Viewport render image I get a black image.
In other render engines this is very simple, just save whatever is being rendered in the virtual frame buffer as is.
Do I really have to re-render the image out every time I want to save it?

"If I press Viewport render image I get a black image", it should not be the case, maybe a bug? Maybe share your file?

Viewport render image only renders Show overlays. If I disable them the image is black.  https://ibb.co/qC4C45z

could you please share your file? make it as simple as possible

@moonboots It is not a bug, Viewport Render Image has always only worked with Workbench and EEVEE render engines, so only with Wireframe, Solid and Material Preview. If you want a Rendered view, you have to either use EEVEE or do a normal render if you want Cycles. Of course this is unfortunate if someone wants a rendered Cycles image with overlays...

@Gordon Brinkmann oh ok I didn't know that, I guess you can answer then

The Viewport Render (no matter if Image or Animation) only works with the Workbench and EEVEE render engines. So if you want to get a rendered viewport image, you cannot use Cycles.
However, if you have no shortcut assigned to the Viewport Render Image option, I personally think simply pressing F12 to get a proper render is quicker for me than going into the menu for a Viewport Render.
And if your render settings have too high samples so that it takes longer to render normally and you want to make a Viewport Render more often - why don't you lower the samples to the same amount as the viewport samples? And you can disable the Compositor if you used it before for rendering, if that's what's bothering you.

Thanks. I'm disappointed. This is such a basic feature in other software. Having to re-render what is already rendered + denoised is really a waste of time.

@mts10 I don't know how long your renders take, but the viewport always renders new each time you change the viewing angle or do anything else, so I'm completely fine with waiting for another render after pressing F12 since I do not have to wait for the viewport to complete rendering if I want to start a proper render. If rendering in the viewport takes such a long time that it's unbearable to wait again for a real render, this would be definitely too long for my taste to work that way in the viewport. But anyway... I can only tell you how it is, I cannot do anything about it. Or use EEVEE

I'm not changing anything. It is already rendered and denoised. I should be able to save it as is and send it to a client, or save it for myself. Shouldn't have to render again. Very basic stuff in other renderers.

As I already tried to explain, "should" will not help you here. And complaining about it several times here will not change anything either, since we are only users, no developers or in any other way affiliated with the Blender Foundation. You can try to request this feature there, but I have never really encountered anybody asking for this.

Thanks for the help. I agree.
